# Upgrading from Mojave 10.14.3 to Mojave 10.14.6 (or at most Catalina), but not to Big Sur?

Tags: mojave, upgrade, big-sur

I have a MacBook Pro (early 2015) with MacOS Mojave 10.14.3, Safari 12.0.3 and XCode 10.3. The webpage I want to remote debug is opened in Safari on an iPhone SE with iOS 14.2.

The answers I got on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55369149/after-latest-update-of-xcode-10-2-web-inspector-is-not-working) suggest that I should upgrade my macOS Safari and/or my XCode version installed on my Macbook.

I see that there is a download for Safari 14.0.1 Beta 4 [but it requires at least macOS Mojave 10.14.6](https://download.developer.apple.com/Safari/Safari_14.0.1_for_macOS_Catalina_beta_4_and_Safari_14.0.1_for_macOS_Mojave_beta_4/Safari_14.0.1_Beta_4_Notes.pdf).

From https://xcodereleases.com/, I see that my current XCode version 10.3 is the latest I can get given my MacOS Mojave version 10.14.3

So I definitely have to upgrade my MacOS version.

When I go to Preferences -> Software Updates, I see this screen:
[image: Software updates screen]

Then if I click on "More info..." under "Other updates are available." I get this screen:
[image: More info screen]

So it looks like I could upgrade to MacOS Mojave 10.14.6, which would allow me to install XCode Xcode 11.3.1 at most and also upgrade Safari to version 14

Great, but I fear that clicking on the "install now" button would also install the latest and recently released "Big Sur" because this is what i see on the Software Updates screen.

So this is my (indeed simple, but I wanted to provide more context) question: **Can I make sure I upgrade to Mojave 10.14.6 only and not Big Sur from the Software Updates screen I see ?**

Answer (score 5):

Yes, clicking on "Install now" in the second screenshot will install only the updates listed and ticked. It will **not** upgrade to Big Sur.

Comment: When you’re ready for Catalina, this link will be handy if you’re still not keen on Big Sur - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683

Answer (score -1):

You can go to https://apps.apple.com/us/app/macos-mojave/id1398502828?ls=1&mt=12 to download Mojave or https://apps.apple.com/us/app/macos-catalina/id1466841314?ls=1&mt=12 for Catalina.